# Using ssh key forwarding from a Vagrant box to a remote server

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant

Trying to get some capistrano deployment scripts to work from a Vagrant Ubuntu VM over Windows to a remote Ubuntu server is failing trying to access github:

```
Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@github.com:company/repo.git on x.y.z.a
DEBUG[28ec78e1]         Error reading response length from authentication socket.
DEBUG[28ec78e1]         Permission denied (publickey).
```

1. ssh -T git@github.com behaves properly in the VM: (hello you, .... message displayed)
2. git is properly set up on the remote machine: (can do a pull w/ username + password, as I don't want to leave my key out on the forward)
3. I believe the scripts to be healthy (other users can successfully run the deployment script as-is)
4. I have tried this with and without ssh-agent-forwarding turned on in the vagrant file - no joy.

What other knobs are there to tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an unexpected solution, so I'll post it for anyone else having mysterious deployment issues:

- local git had been set up using the https url
- remote git had been set up using the public keys.
- deployment appears to validate its keys using the local git first.

There appear to be some issues with mixing the flavors; a clean checkout on the local machine using the git ssh-clone url and the problems went away.

It doesn't quite make sense that this should be the change, but a source diff of the two local repositories shows no changes.
Odd.